# How to catch/throw exception using PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit

I am writing  `JUnit` test case for a method which doesn't throw exception but this method invokes `parse()` method which throws `ParseException` and I need to catch it. I have created one test case where I am passing invalid date format and during debugging it goes in the parse method and then to the catch block but how can I explicitly throw `ParseException` in a test case and then compare the String in the log. Hope I am clear.

Method under test.

```
public static String convertUTC( String strDate, String inputFormat, String outputFormat ) {
    String displayDateString = null;

    try {
        DateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( inputFormat );
        inFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) );
        Date date = inFormat.parse( strDate );

        DateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( outputFormat );
        outFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getDefault() );

        displayDateString = formatDate(date, outputFormat);
    } catch ( ParseException pe ) {
        log.error( "DateUtil.convertUTC :Parse exception while parsing,"+strDate+" using format :"+inputFormat) ; 
    }

    return displayDateString;
}
```

JUnit

```
@Test
public void testConvertUTCParseException() {
    String incomingDate = "2012-08-15T22:56:02.038Z";
    String inputFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm a z";
    String outputFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm a z";

    assertEquals( null, DateUtils.convertUTC( incomingDate, inputFormat, outputFormat ) );
}
```

Apart from the above test case I want to explicitly throw `ParseException` using PowerMockito and do the assert in the log to compare the text. The reason I cannot do it is because converUTC doesn't throw ParseException.

I assume this throws exception but how can I compare the text in the log?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public void testCaughtParseException() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic( DateUtils.class );
    PowerMockito.when( DateUtils.convertUTC( Mockito.any( String.class ), Mockito.any( String.class ), Mockito.any( String.class ) ) ).thenThrow( ParseException.class );   
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.  If you want to cause a `ParseException`, then why can't you just pass an invalid string in your test case?

Comment: This is what I have mentioned already. I am doing that and it is going to the catch block in the method, but I need to explicitly throw exception in my text case. Please take a look at my test case above it is there what you just said.

Comment: Ok, I see.  So it sounds like what you really want is to be able to assert something about the message being logged?

Comment: Yeah, I want to do a assert in the message and I need to write a test case where I could say something like throw ParseException when convertUTC is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly speaking your test case

```
public void testCaughtParseException() throws Exception
```

doesn't make much sense here, as we are already have a try and catch here.
If you throws a parseException from the method then it makes sense to write a test case like this.
In your situation what I would like to do is check if the log.error is getting called in case of incorrect date.

So, I suggest you to use verify of the Mockito.
That would be good enough for your test case.

Comment: In case of incorrect date it is going through the logger and Cobertura even reads it but I wanted to compare the texts you know in a test case. I think verify is a good idea.

Comment: do you think this would work. @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Test
 public void testCaughtParseException() throws Exception {
  PowerMockito.mockStatic( DateUtils.class );
  
  PowerMockito.when( DateUtils.convertUTC( any( String.class ), any( String.class ), any( String.class ) ) ).thenThrow( ParseException.class );
  PowerMockito.verifyStatic( times( 1 ) );
 }